# How to force words in table to be flush left?

Tags: tables, pdftex, tabularx

I have some code (see below) that outputs two tables like below. How can I remove the red area and make the term "nomenclature" flush left like the word "contents"?

```
\minitoc
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    %\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| X | X | X |}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{sb}
        %\hline
        \large\textbf{Nomenclature}  \normalsize   &      \\ \hline
        0         & 2        \\ 
        1         & 3        \\ \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX:SE! By adding `@{}` at begin (and end) of column specification: `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} X X X @{}}`. However, your code fragment is not very clear. Please extend it to complete small document that context of your table will be more clear.

Comment: Thanks you that worked a treat. First time writing a report in LaTeX so communities like this are a fantastic help!

Comment: You are welcome. See answer below, and try to extend your code fragment to an MWE (an example you can see in answer), which reproduce your problem. Knowing it is more easy to help you and maybe give you some off-topic advice, how you can better/easy write your table (or whatever) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me extend my comment to answer, which contain two examples of how you can write your table. Examples are in form of MWE (Minimal Working Example, a small complete document), which can be compiled as it is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
with \verb+tabularx+:
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} X X @{}}
    \hline
\large\textbf{Nomenclature} &   \\ 
    \hline
        0                   & 2 \\
        1                   & 3 \\ 
    \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

with \verb+tabularray+:
    \begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tblr}{hline{1,2,Z},
             colspec = {@{} *{2}{X[l]} @{}},
             row{1} = {font=\large\bfseries,abovesep+=2pt},
             row{2-Z} = {rowsep=1pt}
             }
Nomenclature    &       \\ 
        0       & 2     \\
        1       & 3     \\ 
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]